# Using regex in PHP to filter out valid file names

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a PHP website where registered users can upload an avatar. One of the restrictions is that people can only upload either a .jpg or .jpeg file with only alphanumeric characters, anything else is rejected. This is to make sure I only get uploads like "avatar.jpg", and not "evilcode.php" or "secretcode.php.jpg". I'm also planning other checks, but right now I can't get this first step to work.

I am using this regex expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,150}+\.+(jpe?g)
```

This is the code I'm currently using. The function is called from another php file, with $_FILES['avatar'] as a parameter.

```
public function updateAvatar($avatar)
{
    $regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$';
    $name = $avatar['name'];    
    $result = preg_match_all($regex, $name);
    if($result === 1)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This always returns false, when uploading either "avatar.jpg", "code.php", or "duck.gif". According to the PHP manual, this code should be correct. The method returns either an integer or a boolean, and warns that you should use ===, not == to compare the result. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: You should consider checking the MIME type of the uploaded file.

Comment: Without actually testing this idea.. I think that the result will be 2 and not 1, the entire pattern = 1 + the group = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check yours incoming file through regex, it is possible to upload the [exploit file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) with executable mime, so you must check mime of the file  for safe uploading:

```
public function updateAvatar($avatar)
{
    $available_mimes = array(
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'iejpg' => 'image/pjpeg' // this mime sent Internet Explorer for jpg files
    );

    if(in_array($avatar['type'], $available_mimes)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As for your regex function:

```
public function updateAvatar($avatar)
{
    // Use regex with ignore case flag (for validating jpg and JPG)

    // Uncomment next line, if you want to check files with "_" symbols at name
    // if(preg_match('/^(\w+)\.(jpe?g)$/i', $avatar['name']))

    if(preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g)$/i', $avatar['name']))
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And try to use preg_match()

Comment: `\w` will match `_` too

Comment: if it is problem, use '/^([a-z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g)$/i'. But "_" is correct symbol for file names

Comment: I know but OP says `only alphanumeric characters`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I did not know about exploit files yet. In the future, I plan to use premade frameworks for websites, so I don't create gaping holes in my sites' security.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't have delimiters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$/
```

and you don't need `preg_match_all()` as you check a single avatar file name:

```
public function updateAvatar($avatar)
{
    $regex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$/';
    $name = $avatar['name'];    
    if(preg_match($regex, $name))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

However you'd better change your regex to this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}\.(jpe?g)$/
```

a `+` sign after quantifiers is not needed, also you shouldn't validate multiple `dot`s at the end of name as your requirements.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/ZzXLUy)

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. First, PHP's RegEx functions expect patterns to be surrounded with delimiter characters of your choice (regex options go after the end delimiter).

For example: `$regex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$/';` or `$regex = '|^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$|';`

Second, you use both `{1,100}` ("there are one to 100 characers of the specified class") as well as `+` ("there is one or more charecter of the specified class"). Use only one of those.

Answer (score 0):

try using this,

```
/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i
```

Answer (score -1):

Add delimiters to your regex expression, try this:

```
$regex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}+\.+(jpe?g)$/';
//        ^                               ^
```

Comment: I was thinking the same... I went straight to the point, and it does solve the problem!